# Idiomatic Scala: Map with value type Option

Tags: scala

I have a bunch of entities for which I store values in a map. I know that some of them don't have a value.

Is it good practice to make this explicit by using a `Map[Entity, Option[Value]]`, or would you say that `Map` itself already has these semantics?

Comment: Semantically, the two solutions are not equivalent. If you need to know which entities exist (based on the keyset), then you need to use your solution. However, I still would go with the second approach (using a simple `Map`) and manage the set of all entites in another place. The `Map` then defines a mapping between an `Entity` and its `Value`, and if there is no mapping, then there is no reason to add the `Entity` as a key in the first place.

Comment: Personally I think it makes little sense to use Option as the value (even if you need to deal with default case, you can use `withDefaultValue`). But I have to flag this question since it is rather subjective. perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ should be a better place

Answer (score 2):

Map has the `get` method, which already returns an `Option`, so this is really not necessary, and muddles the type parameters of your map.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `Map[Key, Value]`

`Map[Key, Option[Value]]` is a overkill

For the second case `Map("key" -> None)`. You don't want to keep keys whose value is none

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the use case. You may or may not need to be able to distinguish between "no value" and "no key" scenarios. Imagine, for example, a mapping between user's first name and middle name. 
When the key is present, but value is `None`, that means the user does not have a middle name. If the key is absent, then you don't have a record of that user.

On the other hand, suppose you map a year number to the day of the week on which the 29th of February falls. Non-leap years do not need to be in the map at all in this case, and you can assume, that, if a key is not there, it is because there is no value associated with it.